# Make bootstrap CHECKBOX look like bootstrap BADGE

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'd like to make bootstrap **checkboxes** that *look like* bootstrap **badges**, while retaining the checkbox functionality. I thought maybe I could simply style the checkbox label as a badge, but it didn't work.

```
<head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
</head>
    
        <div class='form-check m-1' style='display:inline-block;'>
        <input id='".$tagDAT[1]."' name='".$tagDAT[1]."' type='checkbox' class='form-check-input form-check-inline'>
        <label class='tag form-check-label text-capitalize' for='".$tagDAT[1]."'>
        <span class='badge badge-secondary'>".$tagDAT[1]."</span></label>
        </div>
```

This code is being echoed from PHP. The checkboxes look like regular checkboxes. It's ignoring the 'badge' code. I thought maybe since it was being echoed via ajax, the bootstrap in the html page wasn't affecting the echoed code. That's why i added the 'head' tag with the bootstrap. Still didn't work.

Anybody have ideas? Or a better way of getting the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the checkbox inside the label
2. Remove the nested `<span>`
3. Apply `.badge .badge-secondary` directly to the `<label>`
4. Apply `.form-check-inline` to the wrapper not the input

Click anywhere on the `.badge` to check/uncheck the box.

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<div class='form-check form-check-inline m-1'>
  <label class='tag form-check-label text-capitalize badge badge-secondary' for='myTag'>
    <input id='myTag' name='myTag' type='checkbox' class='form-check-input'>myTag
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Really close... but the checkboxes still take up space, even when applying style='display:none;'. Any idea what's going on with that? That's the last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Nevermind, display:none; was working, it was the default padding of the div that made it look like the checkbox was still taking up space, but in reality it wasn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 has got [Toggle Buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#toggle-buttons)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btn-check" autocomplete="off">
<label class="btn btn-primary" for="btn-check">Single toggle</label>
```

---

```
<input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btn-check-2" checked autocomplete="off">
<label class="btn btn-primary" for="btn-check-2">Checked</label>
```